# One day, his son developed or encountered a serious stomachache?

Tags: word-usage

> One day, his son_________ a serious stomachache.
>
> A. encountered
> B. developed
> C. led
> D. appreciated

The  multiple-choice question makes me confused.
[Encounter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/encounter) means experiencing something, especially something unpleasant. [Develop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/develop?q=develop%20) means suffering from a illness or a problem.
It seems that both A and B work here.

Comment: What leads you to think *encounter* might work? What leads you to doubt it? Where did you encounter the phrase? What research have you done on your own? What did it uncover?

Comment: The question has been revised.  I wonder if both developed and encountered work here.

Comment: As your dictionary tells you, the _main_ meaning of _encounter_ is _meet_. You encounter a problem in the sense 'come face to face with it'. _Develop_ in this context means **start** _to suffer from an illness_.

Comment: Choice B is clearly the correct choice, but also not really idiomatic. I don't think a simple substitution will make it more idiomatic either. The use of "developed" suggests a serious, chronic condition in my opinion. A more idiomatic rewrite might read something like "One day, his son started suffering from serious stomachaches."

Comment: @CharlesHudgins it might be regional whether it's idiomatic or not. I've definitely heard people say something like "he developed a flu" in movies/tv, because I'm not native English myself and was aware of this phrasing

Comment: As an aside, __stomach ache__ is usually two separate words.  I've never seen them run together like that before.  I'd probably accept "_stomach-ache_" but separate words loos more usual to me.

Comment: @TobySpeight I disagree, "stomachache" looks normal to me and doesn't trip Chrome's spellcheck. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stomachache%2C+stomach+ache%2C+stomach-ache&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019) shows it's been the clear leader since the 1980s.

Comment: Headache, earache, etc are definitely more common than 2 words; I think stomach( )ache is more balanced but it's fine with or without a space.

Comment: I don't know why you link to an English-Chinese dictionary, and then apparently translate the result back to English! You should really learn to use a proper English dictionary if you're serious about learning English and want to find out the precise meaning and usage of words - with a monolingual English dictionary you wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: Have you understood my answer?

Answer (score 12):

This is a question of collocation, and not answerable by logic.  You can "encounter difficulties" (the words "encounter" and "difficulty") do collocate. But not "encounter a disease" - unless you mean "discover a disease" (Scientists first encountered AIDS among young men in San Fransico).

So only "develop" is likely to fill the gap.

Answer (score 6):

[*James K*'s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/342735) is correct that it is not so simple as saying that "encounter" means "meet", since difficulties can be encountered but not met. Nevertheless, it is also not so completely ad-hoc as to require brute-force memorization of every possible collocation.

I think one gloss that works for almost all cases is that "P encounter X" indicates that X shows up to P at a point in time. This explains all the usual cases as well as the one in your question and the one in James' post:

- P encountered a setback.
- P encountered a word he had never seen before.
- (WRONG) P encountered a stomachache. [Diseases are not viewed as point events.]
- Scientists first encountered AIDS in [LA](https://www.nature.com/articles/d42859-018-00002-y).

As *Charles* suggested in a comment, the correct answer is "developed", but it is not commonly used because native speakers usually use "develop" for a disease with a prolonged ill condition, and a stomachache is usually a minor issue. Hence native speakers are more likely to say "One day, his son **had** a serious stomachache.".

Comment: I think that difficulties _can_ be met - though usually we _meet_ them _with_ some opposition (or perhaps with dismay).

Comment: @TobySpeight: That's a different lexical unit altogether (i.e. "meet X with Y"), and so not relevant to the point made in my post. But your comment is certainly useful for non-native speakers.